# Creating an .ico file with multiple sizes - web application

Tags: icon, png, resource-recommendations

I want to be able to create an `.ico` file containing a [complete set of Windows icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx#size) (`16px x 16px`, `32px x 32px`, `48px x 48px`, and `256px x 256px`). Is there a web application that can do this for me given a PNG or BMP that is already `256px x 256px`?

Comment: Hi! I think this question might help you: [How to group ico files](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12726/how-to-group-ico-files/12752#12752). But you need an automatic way to do it, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try with [ConvertICO](http://convertico.org/image_to_icon_converter/).

> This is a batch png to icon converter which allows to create up to 20
>   multiple-size icons from images in png format at a time.

You can select as many output sizes as you need.

---

Another option is [IcoConverter](http://www.icoconverter.com/).

> IcoConverter takes any image and converts it to an ICO pack.

The aspect ratio is not preserved, so squarish images are recommended.

Comment: ConvertIco looks good at first -- but when you actually go to use it, it changes each size you uploaded into it's own icon where it autoscales each size. -- Not super useful if you wanted to specify your own image for each size.  (Windows will already autoscale a 256x256 icon, so unless you wanted more than just autoscaling, what's the point?)

Comment: @IceFire Both the question and answers are from 2013.

Comment: @IceFire It answered the question then, please re-read it. The date should be the main guidance to whether a question is still valid because I would find it a little time consuming to go over the hundreds of answers I wrote since I joined the sites over 12 years ago. You're always welcome to write a better one, it will bump the question to the top of the main site and get votes if better than existing ones.

Comment: @Yisela sorry, given the question, you are right and your answer fits. This still has nothing to do with the year. If an old question is contemporary and an answer does not fit anymore, the answer should vanish. It should then not be your task to check all your old answers, but when confronted with a comment, you should act upon that. I would do that myself on other SE sites

Comment: @IceFire Fair point. I believe there's a way to close old questions when they don't apply any more, but the only way to do so with an answer is to downvote it and leave it a comment. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.icoconverter.com/ did the job for me.

Comment: https://redketchup.io/icon-converter maybe better, supports multiple custom sizes.

Answer (score 11):

If you do it yourself use gimp.org. like Adobe Photoshop, but free. Photoshop does not come with a way to combine a .ICO file or to create it. You can purchase a plugin, but it is risky and Photoshop CC wont work with them.

Gimp allows you to combine and save .ICO files. And it is a free piece of software.

Comment: This ended up working for me. -- I followed [this helpful guide](http://www.catalyst.net.nz/news/creating-multi-resolution-favicon-including-transparency-gimp), with the caveat that I had to use "Export" instead of save.  -- Tl;dr: open your biggest icon file in the Gimp, then open rest using "Open as Layers", so that each icon is a separate layer.  Then use file->export and name it "whatever-you-want.ico", typing the extension is **important**, because it uses a custom dialog for saving, and unlike every other Windows program ever, that's how the Gimp detects what format you want to save as.

Comment: Gimp is the only tool that enables the creation of a favicon from various source files, each with a unique resolution. This feature is crucial if you aim to achieve optimal image clarity in small dimensions.