# Multi-sized ico from different pngs

Tags: favicon

(The next level from [Creating an .ico file with multiple sizes - web application](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17257/20688))

How can I combine multiple `png`s of *different sizes* into a single `ico`? I want the 256x256 and 128x128 versions to look the same, but 32x32 and 64x64 to be from a different file. How can I do this on a mac?

Comment: While the first question mentions only one file and different sizes, [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12726/how-to-group-ico-files/12752#12752) is about different files (I know because I asked it myself :P). Or do you mean to do something else?

Comment: @Yisela Ooh. Sems legit (testing now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I tried doing [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12726/how-to-group-ico-files/12752#12752), I got some cryptic error message when trying to save as PNG… anyway, I eventually did this:

http://regx.dgswa.com/html/Gimp+ico+how+to

> 1. Open your image in Gimp
> 2. Make your canvas square
> 3. Resize your layer to the image
> 4. Scale the layer to the largest size in your .ico file like 64 pixels
> 5. Duplicate the layer
> 6. Scale the duplicate layer to the next size
> 7. Keep duplicating / scaling for all the sizes you want in your .ico file
> 8. Save as .ico

Answer (score 5):

This is actually very easy to do with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

I recently wrote a little utility [faviconbuild](https://theknowledgeaccelerator.com/faviconbuild/) which I have released on github under the [MIT Open Source license](https://github.com/matthewsanders/faviconbuild/blob/master/LICENSE).

[This](https://github.com/matthewsanders/faviconbuild/blob/master/faviconbuild.sh) is a link to the shell script I wrote for Unix / Mac (and Windows if you use Cygwin).  I also provide a [bat](https://github.com/matthewsanders/faviconbuild/blob/master/faviconbuild.bat) file for anyone on Windows.  I would like to encourage anyone to contribute to the project as well, including feature requests.  You can read more about it on the project page and I have also included a link to [download](https://github.com/matthewsanders/faviconbuild/releases/download/v1.0.0/faviconbuild.zip) the ImageMagick binaries I was using during development.

There is a subroutine named createIcon where I do the work, but here is a short example of using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) directly to package different source files into a .ico file.

```
convert "image1.png" "image2.png" "image3.png" "result.ico"
```

The website also has some other usage examples such as the one found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#favicon).

```
convert image.png  -bordercolor white -border 0 \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 16x16 \) \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 32x32 \) \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 48x48 \) \
      \( -clone 0 -resize 64x64 \) \
      -delete 0 -alpha off -colors 256 favicon.ico
```

This does the work of resizing an image and creating an icon with one line of script (or multiline with the \ character at the end of the line).  Obviously this one liner doesn't give you the option to pick and choose the source image per size though.

I have also published a [blog post](https://theknowledgeaccelerator.com/2015/10/10/faviconbuild/) on the development that serves as a mini tutorial for batch/bash for those interested.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small webapp called IcollatorForever that will let you do this.  It's here:

https://adv12.github.io/IcollatorForever/